# Can I find the setting in a drawing for preset

Tags: mesh

I am looking to save a file to a preset. We don't know what or how we achieved the result but we want to create a preset from the file to be applied to all subsequent imports.  I'm looking to unhide hidden curves in a Blender File!

Can this be done? If not, can I send the file to stack exchange for assistance?

Thanks
Dave

Comment: No idea what you mean by 'create a preset', but you can unhide everything in a scene with Alt-H.

Comment: And what imports do you mean? You talk about importing and curves... so I guess you want to import SVG files? When I import an SVG where curves are hidden in the original software, they show up automatically in Blender because it ignores the "hidden" option (at least my Blender does).